# Slow SQL, trying to understand what is going on

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-execution-plan

I have this SQL that started to run very slow on production server ( >20s ). When I run it locally on my laptop on the same DB it runs under 1s.

I know that SQL is not optimal but I tried to run `EXPLAIN` but I don't quite understand the result.

```
SELECT    ST.id, 
          ST.lot_id, 
          ST.warehouse_location_id, 
          WL.name, 
          P.id AS product_id, 
          P.sku, 
          P.code, 
          P.NAME AS product_name, 
          P.has_serial, 
          Sum(ST.quantity) AS qty, 
          Group_concat(ST.id) AS stock_transaction_ids 
FROM stock_transactions ST LEFT JOIN products P 
ON  (P.id = ST.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN warehouse_locations WL 
ON (WL.id = ST.warehouse_location_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
           SELECT stock_transaction_id, 
               Group_concat(serial_id) AS serials 
           FROM stock_transactions_serials 
               GROUP BY stock_transaction_id ) STS 
ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id 
WHERE ( 
    ST.document_type = "Goods transfer" AND
    ST.document_id IN (806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 824, 827, 831, 835, 838, 839, 841, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 890, 944, 945, 946, 954, 955, 956, 957, 961, 965, 966, 967, 2240, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 2249, 2250, 2251, 2252, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260, 2261, 2262, 2263, 2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2281, 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2361, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2375, 2376, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2440, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2446, 2447, 2448, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2455, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2528, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2532, 2534, 2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544, 2545, 2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2556, 2557, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2580, 2581, 2583, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2591, 2592, 2593, 2594, 2595, 2596, 2597, 2598, 2599, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2607, 2608, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2618, 2619, 2620, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 2625, 2626, 2627, 2628, 2629, 2630, 3707, 3708, 10194, 10244, 10246, 10247, 10248, 10249, 10426, 10428, 27602, 27603, 28587, 28588, 28589, 28590, 28591, 28592, 28593, 28594, 28595, 28596, 28597, 28598, 28599, 28600, 28601, 28602, 28603, 28604, 28605, 28606, 28607, 28608, 28609, 28610, 28611, 28612, 28613, 28614, 28615, 28616, 28617, 28618, 28619, 28620, 28621, 28622, 28623, 28624, 28625, 28626, 28627, 28628, 28629, 28630, 28631, 28632, 28633, 28634, 28635, 28636, 28637, 28638, 28639, 28640, 28641, 28642, 28643) ) 
GROUP BY  ST.product_id, 
          ST.lot_id, 
          ST.warehouse_location_id 
HAVING    qty > 0
```

Explain gets me this:
[image]

Can someone help understand what's going on? I will see if I can come back with SQL fiddle as well.

Comment: any pending process on those target tables happening on your production server?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: I am not sure in MySQL, but in SQL server, could either open `Activity Monitor` on that database or query with `sys.process`

Comment: I will look into it

Comment: if you are running the same query against same database, same server. could ignore any solution that will grant performance gain such as indexes, null value, etc. I guess when you ran the query on your side, the pending job might finished.

Comment: @LONG not sure I understand your comment

Comment: Are you running the same query on production server on your laptop?

Comment: @LONG yes the same query on the same dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is your derived table:

```
 ( 
           SELECT stock_transaction_id, 
               Group_concat(serial_id) AS serials 
           FROM stock_transactions_serials 
               GROUP BY stock_transaction_id ) STS 
ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id
```

I can't see you using `serials` anywhere else in the query, so I'm guessing this is not doing very much for you, but the cost is high - the left join isn't using an index when joining. I'd suggest rewriting that as a join on `stock_transaction_serials`, rather than a derived table.

Comment: You are perfectly right... removing this is speeding my query from ~30s down to 0.03s ...

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id 
WHERE ( 
    ST.document_type = "Goods transfer" AND
    ST.document_id IN (806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, -- etc
```

If these values are in goods_transfer_items in a field called id then this would be exactly functionally the same:

```
ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id 
JOIN goods_transfer_items ON goods_transfer_items.id = ST.document_id 
                             AND goods_transfer_items.work_order_number=12345'
                             AND ST.document_type = "Goods transfer"
```

Not only is this much shorter but it will also be much faster because SQL servers can optimize joins.

This is functionally IDENTICAL to the NOT IN

*prior answer below*

---

You should take the values listed here

```
 ST.document_id IN (806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 824, 827, 831, 835, 838, 839, 841, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 890, 944, 945, 946, 954, 955, 956, 957, 961, 965, 966, 967, 2240, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245, 2246, 2247, 2248, 2249, 2250, 2251, 2252, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260, 2261, 2262, 2263, 2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2281, 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2334, 2335, 2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2361, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2375, 2376, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2440, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2446, 2447, 2448, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2455, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2528, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2532, 2534, 2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544, 2545, 2546, 2547, 2548, 2549, 2550, 2551, 2552, 2553, 2554, 2555, 2556, 2557, 2558, 2559, 2560, 2561, 2562, 2563, 2564, 2565, 2566, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2570, 2571, 2572, 2573, 2574, 2575, 2576, 2577, 2578, 2579, 2580, 2581, 2583, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2590, 2591, 2592, 2593, 2594, 2595, 2596, 2597, 2598, 2599, 2600, 2601, 2602, 2603, 2604, 2605, 2606, 2607, 2608, 2609, 2610, 2611, 2612, 2613, 2614, 2615, 2616, 2617, 2618, 2619, 2620, 2621, 2622, 2623, 2624, 2625, 2626, 2627, 2628, 2629, 2630, 3707, 3708, 10194, 10244, 10246, 10247, 10248, 10249, 10426, 10428, 27602, 27603, 28587, 28588, 28589, 28590, 28591, 28592, 28593, 28594, 28595, 28596, 28597, 28598, 28599, 28600, 28601, 28602, 28603, 28604, 28605, 28606, 28607, 28608, 28609, 28610, 28611, 28612, 28613, 28614, 28615, 28616, 28617, 28618, 28619, 28620, 28621, 28622, 28623, 28624, 28625, 28626, 28627, 28628, 28629, 28630, 28631, 28632, 28633, 28634, 28635, 28636, 28637, 28638, 28639, 28640, 28641, 28642, 28643) )
```

Put them in a table, create an index on it and then inner join to it instead of using `IN`

Comment: I have these values already in the table but I am fetching them out in my application layer and putting them into this SQL. Should I do a sub-select instead?

Comment: great... i have all these values in goods_transfer_items.id table field-> 'SELECT id FROM goods_transer_items WHERE work_order_number=12345'

Comment: I have tested the query and the result indeed is the same... Execution time-wise is also the same, does not make it any faster on my production server ~30s... When I run it locally the exec. time is ~0.5s... If it helps here is the explain of the new one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc22gmvvq1rwllk/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-19%20at%2008.40.33.png?dl=0

Comment: @PrimozRome - You need to add an index -- putting it in a table just makes it possible to make the index, now make the index on fk_document_id.  See where it says "using where"?  That means it is not using an index.  The reason the performance is the same is because, as I said, this is functionally identical to the NOT IN, once you have the index then it will be able to seek on the hash and should be O(1).